# RcppParallel shared vectors

Tags: rcpp

In the following example code, one long vector (A), a scalar(dim),a matrix (toadd) and two vectors(rows, cols) were used to initialize the Worker object. The code reduces the long vector into a square matrix, but each time multiplied by the corresponding entries defined by toadd, rows and cols.

The code does not yield the correct answer.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;


struct Lapin : public Worker {
  // input pars
  const RMatrix<double> toadd;
  const RVector<double> input;
  const size_t dim;
  const RVector<int> rows;
  const RVector<int> cols;

  // outputs a matrix
  RMatrix<double> output;

  // two constructors
  Lapin(const NumericMatrix toadd,const NumericVector input,const int dim, const IntegerVector rows, const IntegerVector cols, NumericMatrix output) 
    : toadd(toadd),input(input), dim(dim),rows(rows), cols(cols), output(output) {
  }

  Lapin(const Lapin & jeannot, Split) 
   : toadd(jeannot.toadd),input(jeannot.input),dim(jeannot.dim), rows(jeannot.rows), cols(jeannot.cols),output(jeannot.output) {
  }

  // the working operator
  void operator()(size_t begin, size_t end) {
    for(size_t k = begin; k < end; k++) {
      //Rprintf("k=%d \t",k);
      for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
          //output(i,j) += input(k)+i+j;
          size_t idx_i = rows[i];
          size_t idx_j = cols[j];
          output(i,j) += input[k] + toadd(idx_i,idx_j);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
  // the join
  void join(const Lapin & peter) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      for(size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        output(i,j) += peter.output(i,j);
      }
    }
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix f(NumericVector A, size_t dim) {

  // initialize the toadd matrix;
  NumericMatrix toadd(10*dim,10*dim);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 10*dim; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10*dim; j++) {
          toadd(i,j) = i+j;
        }
  }

  // initialize the rows and columns indices;
  IntegerVector rows(dim);
  for(size_t ir=0; ir<dim; ir++){
    rows(ir) = 1*ir;
  }
  IntegerVector cols(dim);
  for(size_t ic=0; ic<dim; ic++){
    cols(ic) = 1*ic;
  }

  // initialize output
  NumericMatrix output(dim,dim);

  Lapin groumf(toadd,A,dim,rows,cols,output);
  parallelReduce(0, A.size(), groumf);
  return output;
}
```

Please try `f(rep(1,100),5)` to see the error.

This example was motivated by my need to share objects among threads, in this example `toAdd`  in RcppParallel.

Comment: Could you possibly describe what you are trying to accomplish, and provide an example of inputs with the expected output? I can't say for sure, but I suspect you are doing a lot of unnecessary looping that could be avoided entirely.

Comment: Please try the above code. f(rep(1,100),5) should produce a 5 x 5 matrix, all multiples of 100.